# Laravel routing - dynamic redirects set in database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

As part of my CMS I allow a client to set up redirects from old URL's to new page URL's. This needs to be the first thing checked in the web.php routes so I am doing:

```
Route::any('/{any?}', 'RedirectsController@check')->where('any', '.*');
```

This hits the RedirectsController 'check' method as expected:

```
public function check($any = false){

    $any = $any ? '/' . $any : '/';

    $redirect = Redirect::where('url_from', $any)->first();

    if ($redirect)
        return redirect($redirect->url_to, $redirect->type);


}
```

But if a redirect has not been set up by the client, how can I skip this route and move on to the rest of the routes in the web.php file?

Comment: You should use a middleware for that, you'll then be able to pass the request to the middleware and redirect the user only when the route match.

Comment: Of course - thank you!